# LUKS: Change master key

Tags: luks, cloning

I've already read [this SE question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/150774/luks-change-encryption-key), but it's somewhat old now. How can I reencrypt a LUKS partition using a different master key? I have a cloned VM image that needs to go into production, but it's obviously using the original VM's master key. When I install cryptsetup-reencrypt, I see a scary message:

```
[root@server ~]# cryptsetup-reencrypt /dev/xvdd1
```

WARNING: this is experimental code, it can completely break your data.

Comment: Since you're making a copy anyway, why not use `cryptsetup-reencrypt`? If it crashes, you can just throw the broken copy away and make a new one.

Comment: Just make sure the device is not in use and don't reboot the machine until it's done. You're operating in-place on your only copy of data, that's always dangerous no matter what you do.